# Triangle mapped on a sphere in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry

How can I map a triangle on a sphere? I want to visualize (plot or animate) it for my student in Non-Euclidean geometry. I have no restrictions on the triangle's kind or on the sphere in $\mathbb R^3$. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Seen [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TrianglesOnASphere/)?

Comment: @YvesKlett: In fact, I wanted to be informed about the codes. Thanks J.M.

Comment: That is not really compliant with how this site usually works. Is is considered bad style to simply ask for code without at least showing a minimum of prior research. Please look at the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I don't think this question deserves to be closed.  No one is required to answer a "code request" question like this.  Such as question, apart from a history of similar questions, does not warrant closure.  Also, there are several votes on this question for "off topic" yet I believe it has been made clear from the comments and the Accept that this is in fact intended for *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for your comment. To be honest, I didn't post a question here to get +1 or -1. I know what to do it via Maple because I made a similar but not animate small program in that area, but to know that in another environment was my willing. :-)

Comment: Shouldn't you at least specify what kind of mapping you want? I won't close it as per @mr.wizard's request, but I was very much tempted to do so. The question doesn't seem to be directly related to Mathematica and requires quite a bit of interpretative effort of the people here. Could have been much better.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: I wanted to teach to my students that we can map on surface of an sphere to know the non Euclidean geometry better. So, I made a Maple small program which is just a plot not an animation. That's why I asked it here. All Mr. Wizard did is what I was looking for. That is a good idea lighting my teaching style. Thanks for your consideration. I apologize if I brought up my question inappropriately.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard after the answer, comments etc. the migration to math.se does not make sense (even if I voted to migrate to begin with)... is there a way to undo this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Sorry for all troubles I have made for you. I prefer it to be here. I think, it'll be so useful for my friends here. Thanks ;-)

Comment: @Babak holy heck-- well, it's back on *Mathematica* now and I think it's going to stay.  Sorry.  We just had a kerfuffle reversing the migration and I don't want to start another one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It is yours now, dear friend. Ok. I understand. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the comments [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) linked to a [Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TrianglesOnASphere/) by Borut Levart.

Here is code from that, with my own refactoring:

```
eps = 10^-6;

(* from spherical to cartesian coordinates *)
sp[{ϕ_, θ_}] := {Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}

(* part of great circle between two sphere points *)
ark[{r1_, r2_}, nt_] := Table[
  RotationTransform[t VectorAngle[r1, r2],
    Cross[r1, r2]][r1], {t, 0, 1, 1/nt}]

Manipulate[
 If[p1 == p2, p1 = .99 p2];
 If[p1 == p3, p1 = .99 p3];
 If[p3 == p2, p3 = .98 p2];
 Graphics3D[{
   {Red, Opacity[.6], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .995]},
   ark[#, 20] & /@ Subsets[sp /@ {p1, p2, p3}, {2}] // Line,
   PointSize[.015], Point[sp /@ {p1, p2, p3}]
  },
  Boxed -> False,
  ImageSize -> {400, 400},
  FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}},
  FaceGridsStyle -> GrayLevel[.5]
 ],
 {{p1, {4.2, .5}, "point one"}, {eps, π (1 - eps)}, {2 π (1 - eps), eps}},
 {{p2, {.1, 1.1}, "point two"}, {eps, π (1 - eps)}, {2 π (1 - eps), eps}},
 {{p3, {5.1, 1.8}, "point three"}, {eps, π (1 - eps)}, {2 π (1 - eps), eps}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left, SaveDefinitions -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the time you took.

Comment: What a code, huh. :D

Comment: +1 anyway because of all the fuss with the migration :-)

Comment: As it's a simple transform it's not really appropriate, but do you know `CoordinateTransform` (further to the deprecated Vector Analysis package) exists as of 9?

Comment: @Martin, Wizard here is still on version seven, if memory serves...

Comment: @JM cheers, there should be cheat sheets on you experts.

Answer (score 6):

I might as well... let me present here the spherical geometry version of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1477). I shall provide two flavors in this answer as well: one where all the arc lengths are given, and one where all the interior angles are given. The formulae used within those routines are nothing more than an application of the spherical law of cosines.

Now, on to the routines. But first, a few auxiliaries:

```
sphericalDistance[{u1_, v1_}, {u2_, v2_}] :=
                  InverseHaversine[Haversine[v1 - v2] + Sin[v1] Sin[v2] Haversine[u1 - u2]]

GreatCircleArc[p1_, p2_] := Module[{cc, sp1, sp2},
       cc = Cos[sphericalDistance[p1, p2]/2];
       {sp1, sp2} = Append[Sin[#2] Through[{Cos, Sin}[#1]], Cos[#2]] & @@@ {p1, p2};
       BSplineCurve[{sp1, Normalize[(sp1 + sp2)/2]/cc, sp2}, SplineDegree -> 2,
                    SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, SplineWeights -> {1, cc, 1}]]
```

Here, then, is the routine for drawing a spherical triangle on a unit sphere, given the (normalized) side lengths:

```
With[{a = π/5, b = π/4, c = π/3},
     Block[{β = N[ArcCos[(Cos[b] - Cos[a] Cos[c])/(Sin[a] Sin[c])]]}, 
      Graphics3D[{{Opacity[1/2], Sphere[]},
                  {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], 
                   Point[{{0, 0, 1}, {Sin[c], 0, Cos[c]},
                          {Sin[a] Cos[β], -Sin[a] Sin[β], Cos[a]}}]},
                  {Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[3]],
                   GreatCircleArc @@@ Partition[{{0, 0}, {0, c}, {-β, a}}, 2, 1, 1]}},
                 PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 3]]]]
```

[image: spherical triangle from arc lengths]

Here's the routine for drawing a spherical triangle on the unit sphere, given the interior angles:

```
With[{α = π/4, β = π/3, γ = π/2},
 Block[{a, c},
  {a, c} = N[ArcCos[{(Cos[α] + Cos[β] Cos[γ])/(Sin[β] Sin[γ]),
                      (Cos[γ] + Cos[α] Cos[β])/(Sin[α] Sin[β])}]]; 
  Graphics3D[{{Opacity[1/2], Sphere[]},
              {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], 
               Point[{{0, 0, 1}, {Sin[c], 0, Cos[c]},
                      {Sin[a] Cos[β], -Sin[a] Sin[β], Cos[a]}}]},
              {Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[3]],
               GreatCircleArc @@@ Partition[{{0, 0}, {0, c}, {-β, a}}, 2, 1, 1]}}, 
             PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 3]]]]
```

[image: spherical triangle from angles]

I made the normalization that one of the vertices is always $(\theta,\varphi)=(0,0)$; if you want your triangles to be positioned somewhere else, modifying the routines should not be too difficult.