# Geodesics on a sphere

Tags: graphics3d, geography

I need to draw many geodesics on a sphere. Is it better to follow @jose
in [his instructive response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78842/194) 
to the post, [Plot a partition of the sphere given vertices of polygons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78705/194), using `GeoPath` & `GeoGraphics`?

---

[image]

---

Or just compute points along
the geodesic and use `Line` in `Graphics3D`? I know how to do the latter:

---

[image]

          

<sup>Image from [a MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/278670/6094).</sup>

---

I would like the ability to rotate the 3D object with the mouse, which seems not 
possible with `GeoGraphics`? But it seems so inefficient to represent geodesics
by lists of 3D points when there is a `GeoPath` primitive.

**Answered** by J.M.'s link to his `BSplineCurve` arcs code:

---

[image: GSphere]

---

Comment: I gave a routine to draw (acute or obtuse) great circle arcs [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994). If you expect to be drawing reflex arcs and entire great circles as well, the routine there will need to be modified.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks! That might be the solution I'm seeking. Very concise code, exactly what I need.

Comment: That's a snazzy-looking sphere partition you have there! :)