# $3D$ graphic of soccer ball

Tags: graphics3d

How to make a soccer  ball $3D$ graphic?

The following image is from Wikipedia, [Spherical polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polyhedron):

[image: soccer ball]

[Truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) (left) and standard soccer ball (right)

```
PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron"]
```

How do I make an [orthographic projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthographicProjection.html) of the [truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) on the sphere?

How do I show the net of a ball in $3D$ like this:

```
PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "NetImage"]
```

[image: a net]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a soccer/foot ball, updated with an improved surface model:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First create the patches (code below):

```
pl /@ {5, 6}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then stitch them together using [`FindGeometricTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html) to help with the work.

The patches are made using `NDSolve` and simple PDE over a polygonal region.  (Pretty cool, I thought.)

Then they have to be sized and "inflated" (i.e., the underlying element mesh is projected onto the sphere).  There's some elementary geometry involved in that.  The PDE surface represents the leather patch *over* the region, and the solution ends up being added to the height of the inflated element-mesh domain.

```
(* coverings of the patches of n = 5, 6 sides *)
Clear[sol];
sol[n_] := sol[n] = NDSolve[
   {Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - 400 u[x, y] == -20, (* can adjust coefficients *)
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]},
   u,
   {x, y} ∈ Polygon@CirclePoints[n],
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}}
   ]

(* circumradius of a CirclePoints[n] facet *)
crad[n_] := 2 Sin[π/n] PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"];

(* plots of the patches of n = 5, 6 sides *)
plotcolor[5] = Black;
plotcolor[6] = White;
Clear[pl];
pl[n_] := 
 pl[n] = ParametricPlot3D[
   crad[n] Normalize@{x, y, N@Sqrt[crad[n]^2 - 1]} + 
       {0, 0, u[x, y] - Sqrt[crad[n]^2 - 1]} /. sol[n] // Evaluate,
   {x, y} ∈ (u["ElementMesh"] /. First@sol[n]),
   Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 100], plotcolor[n]], 
   PlotRange -> 1, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Graphics3D[
 MapThread[
  GeometricTransformation,
  {First /@ pl /@ {5, 6},
   Flatten /@ Last@Reap[
      Sow[
          Last@FindGeometricTransform[#, 
            PadRight[CirclePoints[Length@#], {Automatic, 3}], 
            Method -> "Linear"], Length@#]; & /@ 
       Cases[Normal@PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron"], 
        Polygon[p_] :> p, Infinity],
      {5, 6}]}
  ]]

(* picture shown above *)
```

There were gaps due to a stupid error in `crad[]`, which are now fixed..

---

**Update (new: gaps removed)**

With `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0.01 Sin[60 ArcTan[x, y]], True]`, you get stitches!

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To remove the little gaps that result, I had to construct an element mesh whose points would line up when the patches are assembled and alter the expression plotted by `pl[]`.

```
emesh[n_] :=
  With[{pts = 4 * 60},   (* 60 corresponds to the BC in sol below.
                            4 is the oversampling; 8 gives slightly better quality *) 
  ToElementMesh@ToBoundaryMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> With[{r = Cos[Pi/n] Sec[Mod[t + Pi/2, 2 Pi/n, -Pi/n]]},
       Most@Table[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/pts}]],
    "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[Partition[Range@pts, 2, 1, 1]]}
    ]
  ];

Clear[sol];
sol[n_] := sol[n] = NDSolve[
   {Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - 400 u[x, y] == -20, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0.01 Sin[60 ArcTan[x, y]], True]},
   u,
   {x, y} ∈ emesh[n]
   ];
```

And if in `pl[]` we plot

```
crad[n] (1 + u[x, y]) Normalize@{x, y, N@Sqrt[crad[n]^2 - 1]} -
  {0, 0, Sqrt[crad[n]^2 - 1]} /. First@sol[n]
```

then we get no gaps (although I get an extrapolation warning, it seems to be right next to the boundary).  In a sense, this seems a better expression to plot anyway.

Comment: Nice! A note: `Norm /@ PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"] // First` can just be `PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"]`, and `Norm /@ Differences@CirclePoints[n] // First` is just `2 Sin[π/n]`, so `crad[n_] := PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"] Csc[π/n]/2`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  I look at the list of `"Properties"`, and when I try them, most of them don't work.  It just feels easier to compute everything.

Comment: wow, nice! It IS a soccer!

Comment: BTW: why is there a `10^-6` perturbation in your patches?

Comment: @J.M. Oops, I forgot to remove that.  I was trying to close the small gaps, but it turns out they were due to another mistake in `crad[]`, now fixed.

Comment: @MichaelE2 This is impressive!

Comment: Ah, a 2D generalization of $\cosh$, I see. Very nice!

Comment: OK, you came ahead here; I definitely can't do stitches. :D

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! I think I'm done now.  The only thing left is to stamp it with the MSE logo. ;-)

Answer (score 27):

I am not sufficiently skilled to be able to fake the ridges along each polygon, so here is my modest attempt:

```
arc[center_?VectorQ, {start_?VectorQ, end_?VectorQ}] := Module[{ang, co, r},
    ang = VectorAngle[start - center, end - center];
    co = Cos[ang/2]; r = EuclideanDistance[center, start];
    BSplineCurve[{start, center + r/co Normalize[(start + end)/2 - center], end}, 
                 SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                 SplineWeights -> {1, co, 1}]]

With[{r = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"]}, 
     Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[],
                 Normal @ N[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Faces"]] /. 
                 p : Polygon[l_] :> {If[Length[l] == 5, Black, White], 
                                     GraphicsComplex[r (Normalize /@ MeshCoordinates[#]),
                                                     MeshCells[#, 2]] & @
                                     DiscretizeRegion[p, MaxCellMeasure ->
                                                      {"Area" -> 0.01}]}, 
                 ColorData["Legacy", "Ivory"], 
                 Normal @ N[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Edges"]] /. 
                 Line[l_] :> Tube[arc[{0, 0, 0}, l], 1/50]},
                Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: fake soccer ball]

---

Michael's beautiful solution has forced me to up the ante a bit. I had some difficulties coming up with a "puffed" version, and here is what I ended up with:

```
With[{r = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"], 
      h = 1/10, s = 1/10 (* controls degree of puffing *)}, 
     Graphics3D[{{Directive[EdgeForm[], Specularity[0.9, 90.]], 
                  Normal @ N[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Faces"]] /. 
                  p : Polygon[l_] :> {GrayLevel[Boole[Length[l] != 5]], 
                  GraphicsComplex[(With[{dd = Clip[2 EuclideanDistance[#, Mean[l]]
                                                   Tan[π/Length[l]], {0, 1}]},
                                        (h + r + dd^2 ((2 dd - 3) h - (dd - 1) s))
                                        Normalize[#]] & /@ 
                                  MeshCoordinates[#]), MeshCells[#, 2]] & @
                  DiscretizeRegion[p, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.05}]}},
                 {ColorData["Legacy", "Ivory"], 
                  Normal @ N[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Edges"]] /. 
                  Line[l_] :> Tube[arc[{0, 0, 0}, l], 0.01]}},
                Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: "puffed" fake soccer ball]

Comment: Very pretty! It's only fair that you get to use your own function after all :-) (+1 of course)

Comment: Thanks @Marco, I'm also glad you found `arc` to be very handy. :)

Answer (score 20):

Below I'll use [@J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) convenient `arc` function from [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994/27951) to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10957/27951):

```
Clear[arc]
arc[center_?VectorQ, {start_?VectorQ, end_?VectorQ}] := 
 Module[{ang, co, r}, ang = VectorAngle[start - center, end - center];
  co = Cos[ang/2]; r = EuclideanDistance[center, start];
  BSplineCurve[{start, center + r/co Normalize[(start + end)/2 - center], end}, 
   SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
   SplineWeights -> {1, co, 1}]]
```

This allows me to easily generate curved arcs in 3D given a center and the two endpoints.

We can then get the **coordinates and connectivity of the edges** of your polyhedron directly from `PolyhedronData`. Those are returned as a `GraphicsComplex`, which I transform into a normal `Graphics3D` object, then replace `Line` with appropriate `arc` expressions:

```
curvedEdges = ReplaceAll[
    Normal@PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Edges"],
    Line[coords_] :> arc[{0, 0, 0}, coords]
  ];
```

... and plot the results:

```
Graphics3D[
  {
   Opacity[0.7], White, PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumsphere"],
   Thick, Darker@Green, curvedEdges
  }, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: beautiful +1  :)

Answer (score 17):

The approach that David took [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83571/731) can be reused in this context like so:

```
vertices[faceIndex_] := N@Part[
   PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"],
   PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "FaceIndices"][[faceIndex]]
   ]

rf[faceIndex_] := Module[{cp},
  cp = Cross @@@ Partition[vertices[faceIndex], 2, 1, {1, 1}];
  Function[{x, y, z}, And @@ (Dot[{x, y, z}, #] < 0 & /@ cp)]
  ]

face[faceIndex_] := ContourPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1
  , {x, -1, 1}
  , {y, -1, 1}
  , {z, -1, 1}
  , ContourStyle -> If[faceIndex <= 12, Black, White]
  , RegionFunction -> rf[faceIndex]
  , Mesh -> None
  , PlotPoints -> 50
  , Boxed -> False
  , Axes -> False
  , Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}}}
  , ContourStyle -> {Specularity[Black], Glow[Black]}
  ]

Array[face, 32] // Show
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is very very nice! The visuals are particularly fetching. (+1)

Comment: An alternative: `With[{polys = First[Normal[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Faces"]]]}, vertices[faceIndex_] := N[polys[[faceIndex, 1]]]]`

Comment: @C.E very nice +1. but why is there  a [dark](http://i.imgur.com/4HIpDb7.png) side on the ball?

Comment: @vito Because there is only one light in one direction, so it only covers half of the ball. To fix it you can either add more lights or return to the default lighting setup with `Lighting -> "Neutral"`, but this setup doesn't look very good.

Comment: @J.M. I find that a lot harder to read/understand. My solution is of the form `Part[coordinates, indices]` and the words *coordinates* and *indices* actually appear in the arguments themselves :)