# Soccer ball truncations

Tags: plotting

A Unit edge `Mathematica` icosahedron is truncated with hexagon central arc length  $ h= 0.3667612 $ that I calculated using spherical trig. How can we take two adjoining points say

```
aa = {(1 + Sqrt[5])/(2 Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]]), 1/2, 
   1/Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]]};
bb = {Sqrt[2/(5 - Sqrt[5])], 0, -(1/Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]])};
Norm[N[aa - bb]]
```

[image]

and on the circumscribed sphere demarcate the white portions by drawing lines  with above $h$ divisions, color the pentagons black and start  (mouse) playing with *standard soccer ball* for fun?

Comment: Related: [3D graphic of soccer ball](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118604/3d-graphic-of-soccer-ball).

Comment: FWIW, I don't understand why this question was closed by the [Community](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), and I did not vote to close it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697649/measure-of-an-angle-subtended-by-each-pentagon-in-a-truncated-icosahedron/3715569#3715569   After the above answer I wished to share  in the hexagon truncation segment length $h$ for unsophisticated reconstruction of the soccerball in Mathematica.