# Soccer Ball Dual

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

To mirror the standard truncated icosahedron, a  dodecahedron of side $AB=1$ is truncated to have 20 triangles and 12 decagons roughly as in the hand sketch:

[image]

Condition of same length of regular spherical  polygon side lengths ( using Law of Cosines/ Sines ) gives arc lengths:

$$ AP= 0.274396,PQ=0.473744, QB=AP ; \;$$

Can you please help to show the triangles,decagons and edges on the circumscribing ball with different colors?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can mash up some of the answers from the football question
[$3D$ graphic of soccer ball](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118604/3d-graphic-of-soccer-ball)

Credit to *J. M.'s technical difficulties♦* and *MarcoB* as this draws on those answers:

```
arc[center_?VectorQ, {start_?VectorQ, end_?VectorQ}] := 
 Module[{ang, co, r}, ang = VectorAngle[start - center, end - center];
  co = Cos[ang/2]; r = EuclideanDistance[center, start];
  BSplineCurve[{start, 
    center + r/co Normalize[(start + end)/2 - center], end}, 
   SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
   SplineWeights -> {1, co, 1}]]

curvedEdges[polyh_] := 
  ReplaceAll[MeshPrimitives[polyh, 1], 
   Line[coords_] :> arc[{0, 0, 0}, coords]];

draw[poly_] := 
 Block[{r = Norm[MeshPrimitives[poly, 0][[1, 1]]]}, 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
    MeshPrimitives[poly, 2] /. 
     p : Polygon[l_] :> {If[Length[l] > 3, Orange, Yellow],
       GraphicsComplex[r (Normalize /@ MeshCoordinates[#]), 
          MeshCells[#, 2]] &@
        DiscretizeRegion[p, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.0025}]},
    curvedEdges[poly]
    }, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]

draw[TruncatedPolyhedron[Dodecahedron[]]]
```

[image: truncated dodecahedron on a sphere]

Comment: Triangle size in  this image smaller than required. where in the code should it be changed?  Error .MeshPrimitives is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive ; .I have v 11.0

Comment: I can't help you with v11 I'm afraid but it's really simple: just use this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118617/72682 
 and replace "TruncatedIcosahedron" with "TruncatedDodecahedron".

Comment: It works for all Polyhedra. In the above image triangles are smaller. Where in the code is  adjustability written in?

Comment: It's not. In 12.1 it's possible to adjust the side ratio with: `TruncatedPolyhedron[Dodecahedron[], 0.3]`. In v11 you'll need to use the `PolyhedronOperations` package: ```<< PolyhedronOperations`;
Truncate[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"], .3]```