# Plot disk in 3D is very slow

Tags: plotting

The following code(plotting disk in 3D) is very slow in Mathematica, how to optimize the code?

```
center = {0, 0, 1};
normalAxis = {0, 0, 1};
radius = 1;
    
region = DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[
        {
                Dot[{x, y, z} - center, normalAxis] == 0 &&
                Norm[{x, y, z} - center] <= radius
            },
        {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: Why do you Normalize a normalized vector??  Why do you define radius when you could simply place $1$ in the code?

Comment: Why not `ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 1} + r {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 0},
 {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 1}]`

Comment: I want to make other operations based on ImplicitRegion. e.g. Projecting some shapes onto sphere.

Comment: I took these code snippets from my code, I replace the variables with constants, please ignore the normalize and unit radius. I think remain the variable names in code could make the code more readable.

Comment: What is `Projecting some shapes onto sphere`?

Comment: Here is an example(sorry for my poor English): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83550/projection-of-triangles-onto-a-sphere

Comment: Here it is pretty much instantaneous. `12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)`

Comment: same here, it is instantaneous in `12.3.0 for Win10 (64-bit)`