# Manipulating 2D graphics along the surface of a 3D sphere according to their centroids' latitude/longitude

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, modeling

I'm trying to make an unsophisticated 3D model of a continent's path on a globe consisting of snapshots of the planet surface that follows the historical trend of continental drift.

By "unsophisticated" I mean:

1. Each continent is represented by a simple polygonal approximation. The approximation is based on the respective continent's present shape.
2. The globe is a perfect sphere.
3. At the start, the supercontinent Pangaea is less a supercontinent and more a jigsaw puzzle whose pieces (the polygons) can overlap. For reference, you can check [this YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwWWuttntio). My starting point would be about $332\text{ mya}$ ([3:34](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwWWuttntio&t=3m34s)) and the terminal point would be what we see today at $0\text{ mya}$ ([4:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwWWuttntio&t=4m12s)).

For the purposes of this post, let's suppose a continent is approximated with a small regular hexagon.

> 1. How can I render a hexagon on a sphere?
> 2. Is it possible to manipulate the hexagon's position on the sphere by means of adjusting the hexagon-on-sphere's centroid's coordinates?
> 3. Would it also be possible to rotate the hexagon?

By this I mean I would like to, with the use of `Manipulate` and sliders, adjust the latitude/longitude of the point on the sphere corresponding to the hexagon's center to place the hexagon wherever I wish - kind of like dragging a coin along the surface of a beach ball.

This is easy enough to do in rectangular coordinates. Given a hexagon like

```
Graphics[Polygon[CirclePoints[6]]]
```

I can translate and rotate it in a plane using

```
Manipulate[
    Graphics[
        Rotate[Polygon[CirclePoints[6] + Table[{x, y}, 6]], t]
       ],
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2Pi}]
```

but I have no clue as to how to adapt something like this to the sphere's surface.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23053)

Answer (score 3):

A polygon on a sphere has a location specified by a vector `h` from the origin to the polygon centroid.

```
PolygonCentroid[p_Polygon] := Mean[Most[p[[1]]]]
```

Begin with a hexagon `p` centred on the North pole. Rotate the North pole polygon in two steps. First, rotate down to the proper latitude `u`, then over to the proper longitude `v`. The latitude between -90 and +90 degrees is converted to a polar angle running from 0 at the North pole to 180 at the South. Combining two rotation matrices is equivalent to the following matrix `m`. The outer Transpose is required so that the rotated polygon `q` may be written as `q=p.m`.

```
Transpose[RotationMatrix[v, {0, 0, 1}].RotationMatrix[Pi/2 - u, {1, 0, 0}]]
```

Finally, use one last RotationMatrix to allow for rotations of the polygon `q` by `a` degrees about its centroid.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{p, q, m, cv, cu, sv, su, h},
      p = Polygon[Table[{0.15 Cos[t], 0.15 Sin[t], 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/3}]];
      Graphics3D[{
         EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
         Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.97],
         Blue, Tube[1.2 {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.04],
         Red,
         cv = Cos[v*Degree]; cu = Cos[u*Degree];
         sv = Sin[v*Degree]; su = Sin[u*Degree];
         m = {
              {cv, sv, 0},
              {-su sv, cv su, cu},
              {cu sv, -cu cv, su}};
         q = Polygon[p[[1]].m];
         h = Chop[PolygonCentroid[q]];
         Red, Tube[1.2 {-h, h}, 0.04],
         Polygon[q[[1]].Transpose[RotationMatrix[a*Degree, h]]]
      },
     Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
     ViewPoint -> {0, -5, 0}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
     BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, 
     PlotLabel -> "h \[Rule] " <> ToString[h],
     PlotRange -> 1.25 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 500]],
   {{u, 0., "Latitude Degrees"}, -90., 90., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{v, 0., "Longitude Degrees"}, -180., 180., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{a, 0., "Rotation Degrees"}, 0., 360., Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

For example:

[image: hexagon on sphere]